# How to copy value from one text input to another with javascript using a link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, input, copy

I have searched and found ways to do this with checkboxes but i would like to use a link.

I have worked out this much of the code but I know I must be missing something simple.

Anyone have any ideas?

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#currencyBtn a").click(function(){
       var value = $('#currencyVal');
       var input = $('.currencyCopy');
       input.val(value);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
MAIN  <input type='text' id='currencyVal' value=''><a href='#' id='currencyBtn'>copy</a>

COPY1 <input type='text' class='currencyCopy' value=''>
COPY2 <input type='text' class='currencyCopy' value=''>
COPY3 <input type='text' class='currencyCopy' value=''>
COPY4 <input type='text' class='currencyCopy' value=''>
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dvhpj5wg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the wrong selector:

```js
$("a#currencyBtn").click(function(){ // target the anchor with an ID of `#currencyBtn`
  // #currentBtn a | not an element with an ID of `#currencyBtn` with a child anchor
  var value = $('#currencyVal');
  var input = $('.currencyCopy');
  // value.val() // get the value first
  input.val(value.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
MAIN  <input type='text' id='currencyVal' value=''>
<a href='#' id='currencyBtn'>copy</a><br>
<br>
COPY1 <input type='text' class='currencyCopy' value=''><br>
COPY2 <input type='text' class='currencyCopy' value=''><br>
COPY3 <input type='text' class='currencyCopy' value=''><br>
COPY4 <input type='text' class='currencyCopy' value=''><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("a#currencyBtn").click(function(){
        var value = $('#currencyVal').val();
        var input = $('.currencyCopy');
        input.val(value);
    });
```